# Top hits aggregation group by

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am using top_hits_aggregation to get my users last visited document. I want to group by the results of top_hits_aggregation.

**Sample Rows Returned:**

```
{
  "lastvisited_users": {
   "buckets": [
     { 
      "top_user_hits": {
        "hits": {
           "hits": [
              { _source: {"c": "s"}},
              { _source: {"c": "s,b"}}, 
              { _source: {"c": "s"}}, 
           ] 
         }
       }
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

I want to group by the results by field "c".

**Expected output:**

```
{
"s": 2,
"s,b": 1
}
```

I am using elasticsearch version 1.7 in production. How to do this?

Comment: Top Hits aggregation does not accept sub aggregations... Can you provide your query? Perhaps it is possible with another solution.

Comment: @MichaelStockerl I explain everything in the link https://jsfiddle.net/6kpoq5zc/1/. 

Thank you